# MongoDB : Sort documents based on an object within an array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection which has a sample object as follows :

```
{
    name : 'Sachin Tendulkar',
    followers : {
        location : {
            countries : [{
                name : 'India',
                count : 12345
            }, {
                name : 'Pakistan',
                count : 12345
            },{
                name : 'Australia',
                count : 12345
            }],
            cities : [{
                name : 'Mumbai',
                count : 12345
            },{
                name : 'Karachi',
                count : 12345
            },{
                name : 'Melborne',
                count : 12345
            }]
            states : [{
                name : 'Maharastra',
                count : 12345
            },{
                name : 'Balochistan',
                count : 12345
            },{
                name : 'Sydney',
                count : 12345
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

I wish to sort all the documents based on the city count. For example,

`Sort all documents according to a specific city i.e. Mumbai's count`

Can you help me build a query for sorting document as per the conditions mentioned above ?

Comment: please post your desired output...or elaborate more

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be the query:

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([
{$unwind:"$followers.location.cities"},
{$match:{followers.location.cities.name:"Mumbai"},
{$sort:{"followers.location.cities.count":1}}
])
```